# Asynchronous call within Callable

Tags: java, android, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Consider the following Java code (a simplified version of what I am working with - if there are errors it's because I haven't run it through a compiler):

```
CountdownLatch latch = new CountdownLatch(collection.size());

for(Whatever thing : collection){

    provider.doWork(thing, result -> {
        process(result);
        latch.countDown();
    };
}

try {
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}

doMoreWork();
```

So I run a number of asynchronous tasks, and wait for them all to be done before proceeding.  Right now I'm accumulating the result of the asynchronous tasks in a list.  This works and it's fine, but I'm looking at whether there's a cleaner implementation using Futures or something similar.  The issue is the asynchronous call.  A Callable is supposed to return the result of its work, but the result of this work won't be known until later.  It's not worth rewriting `doWork` to be synchronous.  Should I just leave this alone, or is there an option out there?  Partly my interest is in better code but partly in just learning more about concurrency options.  If it matters, this is in an Android app.

Comment: can you please try with completableFuture Object with supplyAsync method. It is a concept of java 8 it will help you to solve your purpose.

Comment: Thanks, reading up on that now.  If anyone wants to supply some code using that class, that would be welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately `supplyAsync` is only available in Android API level 24, and I can't set my minimum SDK level that high - too many users would be left behind.

Comment: Really depends on what your constraints are. If it's fine that the method in which this is running is blocking, then leave it alone - the code is fine.
If the method is not intended to be blocking you can consider rewriting it, either to the form where the method returns a future or observable, or takes a callback that returns the accmulated results. That however will also require changes on the caller site.

Comment: It's fine to block, it's in a background thread.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach using ExecutorService and Future, didn't tested on android but all available on level 1 api:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
List<Future<String>> pending = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
for(Whatever thing : collection) {
    Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return doWork();
        }
    });
    pending.add(future);
}
for (Future<String> result : pending) {
    System.out.println("Your result ASAP:" + result.get());
}
executor.shutdown();
```

It will return as soon as the current item is done, in the order the were submitted.